# Get a list of all elements in a scrollable table using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to get a list of all elements of a certain class in a table using Selenium.
The number of elements visible in the DevTools elements' panel depends on the size of the browser window and does NOT reflect the real amount of elements. If I expand the browser window, the list of elements will become larger. In order to see more elements, I need to scroll down manually, but the amount of elements doesn't change still. The thing is, the table is dynamically loaded when scrolling, so elements will appear/disappear from DOM depending on how far you've scrolled.

The screenshot of elements on a WEB-page and Chrome DevTools elements' panel:

[image]

Using `driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath))` does not work and returns an incorrect number of elements, the number that is visible on the page but not the actual amount of elements.

I am trying to test that a certain number of elements is present in a table via UI, but the table has to scroll down to load things. I know you can scroll the page in Selenium, but the elements on the page disappear from the top and get replaced in the bottom when scrolling down through the page. So, I expect 13 elements to be present in a table but the most I am able to get right now is 12 simply because the screen resolution doesn't allow me to enlarge the screen anymore.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: You might try building a hashmap of webelement references, but if you also get info from those elements, do that before scrolling, and store those things in a hashmap.  Make sure the key of the key-value pair is unique for each webelement or value stored.  (That might just be an ID for each element...)  When you are done scrolling, get the size.

Comment: @pcalkins How do I make sure that I've scrolled to the bottom of the elements' list? Comparing by name could be tricky because the elements might have the duplicate name.

Comment: Just see if the size of the hashmap has changed.  If it has, then scroll again.  If not, I'd guess you've reached the end.  You'll need to identify what's unique about those elements.  If the site's designed well they will have unique IDs, so use those as the keys in the hashmap.  Also be sure to check for stale element exceptions... those could occur if the list of elements is still loading. (get them again)

Comment: @Andrei Suslov can you share URL?